# Differents between single and singleOpt in Play framework and scala

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

In play framework the Anorm method using single and singleOpt. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 4):

As is often the case with methods suffixed with "opt", it means that it returns an `Option`. So the difference between those 2 methods is that `single`will treat the absence of result as an error, while `singleOpt` will just return `None` when there is no result (and the actual result wrapped in `Some` otherwise).